# Send pandas dataframe as csv using Falcon

Tags: python, pandas, falconframework

I currently have a pandas dataframe, I want it to get downloaded when you hit an API endpoint using Falcon.
Currently I have following code.

```
data = df
resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
resp.stream = data
resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
```

How can send the contents of my dataframe over the network to so that it gets downloaded when you hit the API endpoint?
Any help is Appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Convert to csv, compress as gzip and send.

Comment: Could you suggest any good links to the documentation that shows me how to do so/

Comment: Do you want to host the file or do you want to download it?

Comment: I want to host so that clients could hit the end points and download it

Comment: Okay. There are some links.

Comment: And alternatively: http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/tutorial.html#

Comment: This did not help me much in terms of sending the csv

Answer (score -1):

First you must transform the DataFrame into something suitable for sending.  Easiest is probably `to_json()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html because JSON is the easiest language to parse in most web clients.

Comment: I am able to send it as json, I need to send it as a csv

Comment: Well then use `to_csv()`.

Comment: I tried it doesn't download as csv. There is no file extension to the downloaded file